# How do I get globally installed node modules to run on terminal

Tags: linux, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am learning how to code with react, and I have installed the create-react-app on my computer. However, globally installed node modules are not running on terminal.

I installed create-react-app globally. I can find find the folder, but I don't know how to get the command to run. Please how do I get globally installed node modules to run on terminal. I used yarn for the installation.

Answer (score 0):

for create-react-app, you should be able to simply run 
`create-react-app` then the name of the App you are creating

so:

`create-react-app nameOfApp`

Here is some documentation that should help: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-new-app.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to start the application, you can use

```
node server.js
```

if your entrypoint file is called server.
Alternatively use npm start, documented here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start

To see what is installed,

```
npm -g list
```

will tell you what is installed globally.

Comment: I'm not asking about starting. I'm asking about how to use create-react-app via Linux terminal. I've installed it globally but it doesn't run on terminal.

Comment: if you type

`
which create-react-app
`

do you get 

`
/usr/local/bin/create-react-app
`

or something else ?
how about 

`
$ create-react-app -V
`

?

Comment: I get nothing and the message I get for running create-react-app -V is bash: create-react-app: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue and this is how I did it:

I found the location where my global packages where being installed and exported the path to the .bin directory

export PATH=$PATH:~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin